# select distinct numbers sql Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a table named **messages** in which there is a field name **mobile numbers**.
The numbers are in this format:

**12345678** and **+9112345678** .. so they both are same..the only difference is that in one number the country code is missing.

so I query in the database that

```
select the **distinct** numbers from messages tables..
```

Now it is taking these both numbers as **distinct**.. but what I want is take these both numbers as one. 
 **How can I do this?** and in my DB there are several numbers with different country codes. Some has a country codes and some not, but I want to take both as one. The one in country code and the other without code. How can it be done?

Comment: This is not really possible to do _correctly_ for multiple countries. For example, `12345` will be considered the same as `+112345` even if it's really `+4612345` if it had been saved with a country code. Of course, you can guess, but it'll just be an estimate, not 100% correct.

Comment: Maybe compare just the right N characters, instead of the entire string then.

Comment: this is what happens when you don't normalize your tables n_n you table field is not atomic, it provides two different informations: the telephone number and the area code. You might find a solution to your problem, but the cleanest way is to separate them into two different fields

Comment: @Tim is it possible in SQL? i mean is there any query to compare the right characters

Comment: Sure is possible., e.g. SELECT distinct right(phone_string, 9) FROM messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a query that's supposed to be done in "real time", your table contents aren't going to be ideal (read: horrible performance)

That said, you can make an approximation of the correct result if you know all the country codes and their local prefix (for example, a local number in Sweden is something like `092066666` while with country prefix the `0` is removed to `+4692066666`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE country_codes (
  id INT,
  code VARCHAR(5),
  local_prefix VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO country_codes VALUES
(1, '+46', '0'),
(2, '+91', '');
```

...and then you can do a query like;

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 
  CASE WHEN SUBSTR(number,1,1) = '+' 
       THEN REPLACE(number, 
                    (SELECT code 
                     FROM country_codes
                     WHERE SUBSTR(number, 1, LENGTH(code)) = code), 
                    (SELECT local_prefix 
                     FROM country_codes
                     WHERE SUBSTR(number, 1, LENGTH(code)) = code))
       ELSE number
       END) "distinct numbers"
FROM numbers;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85f14/13).